# Sencha Cmd v3 build error when implementing Bryntum Scheduler

Tags: extjs, bryntum-scheduler

Using Cmd 3.0.0.141, I have successfully generated a workspace and an Ext app in that workspace. The application builds correctly until I attempt to integrate the Bryntum Scheduler, where I encounter an error when I try to build:

"Failed to resolve dependency Sch.panel.SchedulerTree for file ExtCalendar.view.Tree"

the app is very simple at this point, uses Ext.application and follows the MVC pattern where I have a view defined "ExtCalendar.view.Tree" that extends 'Sch.panel.SchedulerTree". I also have models and stores that extend Bryntum classes as well, so I assume the compiler will trip over those as well, since it can't see the Sch namespace.

I've added a 'js' path to my app.json that points to the bryntum js file where 'Sch.panel.SchedulerTree' comes from. I've tried to run the 'refresh' command with the same results (Failed to resolve...). I've regenerated the bootstrap.js file manually using 'compile', but nothing from the Sch namespace ever gets added to it, despite the Brytum lib file being in the classpath.

What do I need to do in order to successfully run the 'build' command with libs like this?
Or, do I need to take a more granular approach using the 'compile' command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the nice folks on the Sencha forums, I was able to resolve my build issues. The solution, for me, involved a shim. I added an external shim.js file to my index with as many //@require and //@define directives as needed in order to resolve the dependency issues.

According to the nice folks at Bryntum, once I upgrade from the free-trial version of the Bryntum Scheduler, I will be able to get rid of the shim and simply rely on the sencha.cfg classpath pointing at the Bryntum src.

Also, as an aside, the app.json file is not used in ExtJS apps, its inclusion in the generated files was a bug in build 141 of Cmd v3.

See [this thread](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?244300-Does-Cmd-v3-support-vendor-libraries) for more detail.